# How to make my cocoa application occupied lower memory and CPU resources

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, memory-management

I want to send the screen's mirroring to another computer.My idea is to send 15 screen capture images pre second.I written some code as following，it worked.

```
while(YES) {
  [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFormConnection:videoConnection
                        completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer,NSError *error){
  NSdata *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
  NSArray *sort = [[NSArray alloc] init];
  NSUInteger length = [imageData length];
  NSUInteger chunkSize = 9200;
  NSUInteger offSet = 0;
  do {
     NSUInteger thisChunkSize = length - offSet > chunkSize ? chunkSize: length - offSet;
     NSData *chunk = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(char *)[imageData bytes] + offSet;
                                        length:thisChunkSize
                                  freeWhenDone:NO];
     sort = [sort arrayByAddingObject:chunk];
     offSet += thisChunkSize;
  } while(offSet < length);

  GCDAsyncUdpSocket *sendImage;
  sendImage = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
  for(int i = 0;i < sort.count;i++) {
     [sendImage sendData:[sort objectAtIndex:i] toHost:@"239.1.1.110" port:46110 withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.0012f];
  }
  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.002f];
}
```

But the problem is that with the time goes by, the application occupied more memory and CPU resources. I just want to continuously capture and send the image. I'm new to Cocoa Programming, I know few Memory Management.

Maybe my solution is stupid，can anybody help me to modify the code more efficient? Or give me some useful advice?

Any Help is appreciated,thanks a lot in advance.